# Cutting a python output with awk/sed/bash

Tags: python, linux, bash, awk, sed

I am attempting to print on separate line or extract all of the following entries:

```
['zzb', 'zzc', 'zzd', 'zze', 'zzf', 'zzg', 'zzh', 'zzi', 'zzj', 'zzk', 'zzl', 'zzm', 'zzn', 'zzo', 'zzp', 'zzq', 'zzr', 'zzs', 'zzt', 'zzu', 'zzv', 'zzw', 'zzx', 'zzy', 'zzz']
```

The same are generated with a python script. I am attempting to pipe all results to a for bash cycle such as:

```
for i in $(python pythonscript.py); do something $i; done
```

My knowledge on linux commands is sort of basic and I only end up with things such as:

```
python pythonscript.py | awk -F"'|'" '{print $2}'
```

but since the entries are printed in a single string, this only gives me a single result.

Maybe my python script is incorrect, I would basically like to have a permutation of all 3 letter possible combinations generated from the - **A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, L, M, N, O, P, R, S, T** alphabet characters that I could later pipe to a for cycle such as:

```
asd
bcd
ghl
llc
bbo
```

However, I do not have the required knowledge and ended up using:

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase
keywords = [''.join(i) for i in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat = 3)]
print(keywords)
```

from a different question here on stackoverflow.

Any help on the matter will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't parse the output with Bash.
Change the Python script to print in the format you like.

For example:

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase
for t in product(ascii_lowercase, repeat = 3):
    print(''.join(t))
```

Comment: Omg you are a god, thank you so much. I also figured out how to print the permutations only with the alphabet characters that I want to use. 

Thank you very much again.



Thank you in advance.